# Looking for the complete game score of Vlastimil Jansa-Istvan Bilek, Rubinstein Memorial 1968

Tags: famous-games

I am looking for the complete score of the game **Vlastimil Jansa** versus **Istvan Bilek**, **Polanica-Zdoj, Rubinstein Memorial 1968.**

Here are the first 20 moves of this Sicilian Dragon-Yugoslav Attack game that have been reconstructed.

```
[Title "Vlastimil Jansa-Istvan Bilek, Polanica-Zdoj Rubinstein Memorial 1968"]
[FEN ""]
[startply "38"]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 g6 6. Be3 Bg7 7. f3 Nc6 8. Qd2 O-O 9. Bc4 Bd7 10. O-O-O Qa5 11. Bb3 Rfc8 12. g4 Ne5 13. Kb1 b5 14. h4 b4 15. Nd5 Nxd5 16. exd5 Nc4 17. Bxc4 Rxc4 18. Nb3 Qb5 19. h5 Rac8 20. Na1!
```

This is the key position where Jansa played the fantastic backwards move 20. Na1! The opening sequence to this game could have been a little different however. The position after the first 19.5 moves should be correct. I have searched on ChessBase 15 and the Internet, but have been unable to find this game. I learned about this position from a video by IM Danny Kopec, which I no longer have, but I don't believe he gave the whole game. I would like to find out the actual moves played, especially those after move 20. In addition I would like to know the game result.  I would most appreciate if you could help me find this piece of chess history!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AehdMxdrB8Y is a link to the video. The games starts at 3:59 and continues from the position you've given.

Comment: Thank you very much for researching this Sicilian Dragon position.  I really appreciate it. My guess is Jansa won as Kopec gave White the advantage.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the full game, as constructed from the OP's question and the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AehdMxdrB8Y) by IM Danny Kopec.

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 g6 6. Be3 Bg7 7. f3 Nc6 8. Qd2 O-O 9. Bc4 Bd7 10. O-O-O Qa5 11. Bb3 Rfc8 12. g4 Ne5 13. Kb1 b5 14. h4 b4 15. Nd5 Nxd5 16. exd5 Nc4 17. Bxc4 Rxc4 18. Nb3 Qb5 19. h5 Rac8 20. Na1 e6 21. hxg6 hxg6 22. Qh2 exd5 23. Qh7+ Kf8 24. Bh6 Bxh6 25. Qxh6+ Ke8 26. Qh8+ Ke7 27. Qh4+ f6 28. Rhe1+ Kd8 29. Qxf6+
```

Thesee three things not clear from the video:

1) What were the moves before 20. Na1?
2) Did the game continue on or not?
3) What was the outcome of the game?

Regarding 1)-The moves seem very reasonable to me since a large part of it is theory.

Regarding 2)-Perhaps. The position after 29. Qxf6+ is basically lost for black, but is not without hope. The white knight is currently out of play and there are still attacking chances for black, e.g. with a pawn storm.

Regarding 3)-It is likely that white won-see above.